# Spring Data, how to merge entity before save?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Suppose i have following classes:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn
    private Job job;
//getters.. . setters

@Entity
class Job {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;
//getters... setters
```

If i will create Person objects, that looks like

```
{ id:0, job: {id: 1, name: "newName", description: null}}
```

Then it will be saved as is, i mean that column description will be owerwrited, and become `null`, how can i tell it, to update only fields that are not `null`, and merge old values into `null` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no this is not possible, spring will assume that you have set the properties to null because you want to delete them, beacause of that you have to come up with your own solution 
ex: - 
you can read the previous object and set those details to the current object.

Comment: That's the point, i have the values from the client side, and there is nothing more, but only id's and some other fields, so each time i need to query object with that id from database, manually merge it, save my object. I want to get rid of that extra query.

Comment: Are you using form binding feature when editing the bean